# How can I select random characters in a pythonic way?

Tags: python, random

I want to generate a 10 alphanumeric character long string in python . So here is one part of selecting random index from a list of alphanumeric chars.

**My plan** :

```
set_list = ['a','b','c' ........] # all the way till I finish [a-zA-Z0-9]

index = random()    # will use python's random generator
some_char = setlist[index]
```

Is there a better way of choosing a character randomly ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The usual way is random.choice()

```
>>> import string
>>> import random
>>> random.choice(string.ascii_letters + string.digits)
'v'
```

Comment: `string.letters` is a bit tricky, because it depends on the locale and is no longer available in Python 3. I would use `string.ascii_letters + string.digits` for OP's use case.

Answer (score 4):

try this:

```
def getCode(length = 10, char = string.ascii_uppercase +
                          string.digits +           
                          string.ascii_lowercase ):
    return ''.join(random.choice( char) for x in range(length))
```

run:

```
>>> import random
>>> import string 
>>> getCode()
'1RZLCRBBm5'
>>> getCode(5, "mychars")
'ahssh'
```

if you have a list then you can do like this:

```
>>> set_list = ['a','b','c','d']
>>> getCode(2, ''.join(set_list))
'da'
```

if you want to use special symbols , you can use string's punctuation:

```
>>> print string.punctuation
!"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\]^_`{|}~
```

Comment: Why is `string_ascii_uppercase + string.ascii_lowercase` necessary? Python has `string.ascii_letters` built in for use in that very case.

Comment: @RicardoAltamirano yes you are right. This code I am using in my work. So I given here from my code

Answer (score 2):

`random()` isn't a function on its own. The traditional way in Python 3 would be:

```
import random
import string

random.choice(string.ascii_letters + string.digits)
```

`string.letters` is contingent on the locale, and was removed in Python 3.