# How do I assign a randomly selected letter from a string to a variable in python?

Tags: python

First, I would like to say I am new to coding and python in general. I just learned about importing and the random function.

Anyways, I am trying to create a text game, in python, where a letter is chosen randomly from some string/word and the user has to try and guess which letter was chosen. I think I understand how to do for loops well enough so that it continues until the correct letter is chosen, but I have no idea how to even go about randomly choosing the letter.

I would just like some help getting started. Thank you.

Comment: Did you check this [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2823316/generate-a-random-letter-in-python][1]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I select random characters in a pythonic way?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14832105/how-can-i-select-random-characters-in-a-pythonic-way)

Answer (score 1):

Since strings are sequences in Python, you can use `random.choice` to pick a random element from a list - in your case, a random letter in a string.

```
>>> import random
>>> c = random.choice("abcdefgh")
>>> c
'g'
>>> c = random.choice("abcdefgh")
>>> c
'a'
```

The `>>>`'s are from the REPL console (running Python by itself) and shouldn't be included if you include the code in a python file.

Answer (score 0):

There is a [library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#functions-for-sequences) for randomizing things. Simply use it like this:

```
import random
text = "Some text"
your_variable = random.choice(text)
```

and you get your random letter from a sequence in that case which is saved in `your_variable`.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are relatively new to programming, I'd like to give you an informative example of the game to clarify some concepts.

1. String `str` is implemented as sequence in Python (you can think that a string is an array of chars). So it supports indexing `s = 'abc'; print(s[1]);` shows `b`.
2. The standard library `random` includes a bench of functions to carry out randomized operations. As mentioned in the other answers that the function `random.choice` randomly pick an element from a sequence. So it can be used to randomly pick a character from a string.
3. You mentioned loops and you seem to be able to master them. So I hereby use another approach called **recursion** to continue the game until the desired answer is found.
4. The game is written in an **Object-Oriented** manner. If you gonna be a developer latter in your career, it's good practice to see this.

Here is the Code:

```
import random

class Game:

    def __init__(self, string):
        self.string = string

    def start_game(self):
        self.answer = random.choice(string)
        self.ask_player()

    def ask_player(self):
        char = input("Just enter your guess: ")
        self.cheat(char)

        if char == self.answer:
            print("Bingo!")
            return None
        else:
            print("You missed, try again! (Or press Ctrl+C to goddamn exit!)")
            self.ask_player()

    def show_answer(self):
        print('The answer iiiis: %s \n' % self.answer)

    def cheat(self, user_input):
        if user_input == 'GG':
            self.show_answer()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    string = "This is the string from which the letters are ramdomly chosen!"
    gg = Game(string)
    gg.start_game()
```

Some test runs:

```
Just enter your guess: 2
You missed, try again! (Or press Ctrl+C to goddamn exit!)

Just enter your guess: T
You missed, try again! (Or press Ctrl+C to goddamn exit!)

Just enter your guess: GG (Haha, I left a cheat code in order to get the right anwser!)
The answer iiiis: o 

You missed, try again! (Or press Ctrl+C to goddamn exit!)

Just enter your guess: o
Bingo!
```